# Applying Heaviside Function definition

Tags: laplace-transform

For the Heaviside function: e^(-cs)*F(s)=u(t-c)*f(t-c) I have 2 questions.

1. How is f(t-c) evaluated?   If for instance my f(s) is 1/(s-2) and my e^(-cs) was e^(-3s) the answer should be u(t-3)*e^(2(t-3)).  Apart from seeing that constant of 2 being left outside and a 3 being subtracted from the "t" I'm not getting what is happening.  Is it f(t) - { f(t) evaluated at c}?

I'm reading that there is a shift of (3 units) happening here but that does not help me understand.
2. Is that value of C from the equation always positive?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse Laplace  transform of $$e^{-cs}F(s)$$ is $$ u(t-c)f(t-c)$$  Thus$$\frac {e^{-3s}}{s-2}$$  will change to $$ u(t-3)e^{2(t-3)}$$

The  answer to your second question is yes, we shift  functions to the right so c is positive.

Comment: Firstly thank you for the quick response.  To expand on my question, why would writing the solution as u(t-3) e^(2t-3) be wrong? (aside from the fact that it is wrong).  From the examples of this type i'm seeing a pattern of simply tacking on a value of (-c) to the value of the exponent.  Does the 2 on the outside necessitate a need for parentheses?

Comment: Thanks for your attention . You need to change $t$ to $t-3$ which results in $e^{2(t-3)}$

Comment: I've spent the last 3 hours toying around with different values of "t" in order to make sense of this.  You have no idea how much your last remark just helped.  Thanks.

Comment: @MisterOH Thanks, I am glad that you figured it out.